# Тестирование функционала in-app покупок

Tags: in-app-purchases, ios

Только начал изучать функционал in-app покупок в iOS. Хочется узнать каким образом их можно протестировать. Xcode 5 обещает облегчить встраивание данного функционала, пока я правда не понял как. И в частности возможно ли это на симуляторе ( с живыми устройствами проблем нет, но интересно).
Спасибо!

Comment: раньше (до 6.х включительно) данный функционал не работал на симмуляторе в принципе, что сейчас не знаю. Тестировать можно было в т.н. песочнице - т.е. не на боевом сервере эппл, а на тестовом, который не берет реальных денег. Но вообще что касается ин-апп большая его часть реально выполняется внутри системной библиотеки, приложение по факту получает параметры продукта по его айди и подтверждение покупки (ну или неудачи покупки), даже список продуктов нужно либо зашивать намертво, либо получать со своего сервера

Answer (score 1):

На сайте Apple есть [описание](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html) того, что нужно сделать, чтобы проверить покупки.
Но если в двух словах, то в iTunes Connect создается тестовый юзер, тестовый продукт.
На девайсе нужно вылогиниться из AppStore, вводить тестовый логин и пароль нужно из приложения.

> Important: Don’t enter your test account information in the Store settings panel. Doing so may invalidate your test account.

В приложении указывается/запрашивается тестовая айдишка продукта.

Более детально расписано в доках